# Hive + maven: how to overwite pom?

Tags: maven, hive, pom.xml

I'm trying to use apache hive in a maven project. I wanted to use Hive 0.9.0 and Hadoop 1.0.4 (they should work together according to http://hive.apache.org/releases.html)

Unfortunately, the pom for hive-common-0.9.0 in the maven repos has a dependency on hadoop-core, version 0.20.1 hardcoded. Is there a way to configure my project to ignore that fragment of the pom? (Version 0.20.1 of hadoop is quite legacy and is not available in maven repos)

Comment: in your title, do you mean _Override_ or _Overwrite_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've found it. Maven allows you to define exclusions for dependencies. In my case it should look like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>  
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>         
</dependency>
```